Scale dependent density growth in sub-horizon scales
In standard cosmology, we use
\begin{equation}
\ddot{\delta} + 2 H \dot{\delta} - 4 \pi G_N \rho \delta=0
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
to study the structure growth in sub-horizon scales. However, at the moment, I am working with a model that considers time dependent gravitational constant which introduces additional term to the above equation:
\begin{equation}
\ddot{\delta_k} + 2 H \dot{\delta_k} +(- 4 \pi G_N \rho  + \frac{1}{3}\frac{k^2}{a^2H^2}\frac{\dot{G}}{G})\delta_k=0
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $G_N$ - universal gravitational constant and when $G =1$ we recover the standard form. I have several questions:
1. Will I be able to use RSD (redshift space distortion) $f\sigma_8$ datasets for the model Eq.(2) to study $\sigma_8$ tension?
I went through the sources that collected $f\sigma_8$ for different redshifts $z$, but I can't see them mentioning at which $k$ they conducted their surveys. I believe they considered such $k$ that lies in between $k \in (0.01h, 1h) Mpc^{-1}$ that barely touches the Hubble horizon up to regimes where non-linear effects start to dominate.
2. How should I approach Eq.(2) to study $\sigma_8$ tension?
If the answer to the first question is positive, then I thought of conducting MCMC simulation using $f\sigma_8$ datasets to obtain $(\sigma_8, \Omega_{m,0})$ confidence contours for several values of $k$ that I will pick from $(0.01h, 1h) Mpc^{-1}$. Will it be a justifiable approach to take into account the scale dependence of my model?
3. Technical question
Since the above equations were derived in natural units where speed of light is $c = 1$,  should I transform $\frac{k^2}{a^2 H^2}\rightarrow 9 \cdot 10^{10}\frac{k^2}{a^2 H^2}$? Or since I pick $k \in (0.01h, 1h) Mpc^{-1}$ then $9 \cdot 10^{10}\frac{k^2}{a^2 H^2} \rightarrow 9 \cdot 10^{10}\frac{n^2}{10^4a^2 H^2/H_0^2}$ where I used $H = 100 h_0$ and $n\in(0.01,1)$?
Thank you in advance for your answer!
